# ReactJS, SocketIO & Redux - What is the right design

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io

What is the best pattern for a large multi-component ReactJS app to integrate with a socket io back-end server?

Here are some of the requirements

1. The React application must connect to the backend (a server using a Flask-based socket.io implementation) upon login. The connection must be torn down on logout
2. The connection should be managed from a central place (as in I don't want every component to connect/disconnect to socket-io). This should also be a place to manage life-cycle of the socketio connection (disconnect, reconnect, etc).
3. Back-end will send async updates (a.k.a statistics for various components). These stats must be handled by the common socketio handling instance and pushed into **redux** store. The message body will have enough information to demux the messages.
4. The components themselves, should (preferably) not know about socket-io, they operate on the redux state.
5. Components can dispatch actions, that could potentially result in sending out a socketio message (to back-end).
6. [I don't have a use-case where a client needs to talk to another client.]

Few questions:

1. What is the right way to design this? At what point should I connect to socket-io?
2. I have a basic-layout component which is used by all pages. Is this the right place to hook up socket-io call? However, I see that this component is unloaded/loaded for each page. Somehow, this doesn't feel like the right place
3. I have seen some examples where every page opens a socketio connection. I am not sure if this is the right model?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably store your socket on a [Context](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html), so that you can create your socket on your **index.js** file, like I did here :

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import { MainProvider } from "./context/MainContext.js";

const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:1234"; //Your backend endpoint

ReactDOM.render( 
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MainProvider value={{socket: socketIOClient(ENDPOINT)}}>
      <App />
    </MainProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Then as it is on the context, you can access it in any component, like that :

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import MainContext from "./context/MainContext"; //import your context here

const myComponent = props => {

    const myContext = useContext(MainContext); //your context is stored in a prop

    return (
        <div></div>
    );
};

myComponent.propTypes = {
    
};

export default myComponent;
```

Finally you can access your socket in the component by calling `myContext.socket`